# How to get two widgets in grid layout to be flush against each other?

Tags: python, tkinter, label, spacing

I am trying to build a messaging system in a tkinter window, in which I'm using grid layout. I want to place a label on top for the messages, with an Entry right below it for people to type in; thus, I want them completely flush. I found pady and ipady which are supposed to do this, but even after setting both to 0:

```
Label(mainframe, background='white', text='asdasdasdasdasd', anchor=W, justify=LEFT, bd=1, relief='solid').grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=(W,E), columnspan=3, pady=0, ipady=0,padx=0,ipadx=0)
Entry(mainframe, background='white', bd=1, relief='sunken').grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=(W,E), columnspan=3, pady=0, ipady=0, padx=0,ipadx=0)
```

The code generates the image below, with space still inbetween the elements. Not sure how to fix this - all my googling tells me that all I should need to do is set pady and ipady to 0, but apparently this does not work. All help is appreciated.

[image: What the code generates]

**EDIT:**

Here's the full code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("title")

mainframe = Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


Label(mainframe, text='Left Label').grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(W, E), rowspan=2)
Label(mainframe, background='white', text='asdasdasdasdasd', anchor=W, justify=LEFT, bd=1, relief='solid').grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=(W,E), columnspan=3, pady=0, ipady=0,padx=0,ipadx=0)
Entry(mainframe, background='white', bd=1, relief='sunken').grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=(W,E), columnspan=3, pady=0, ipady=0, padx=0,ipadx=0)
Label(mainframe, text="Center Area").grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=W, rowspan=2)

Label(mainframe, text="Right Label").grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=W, rowspan=2)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: In my computer,they are linked together.Maybe problem is not here.Could show a minimal example?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA I added the full code I'm working with.

Comment: The second to last line adds padding to all objects in `mainframe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)` in the last.This will add the padding of each widget in the `mainframe`.

The fastest and easiest way to do that and don't change the padding of other widgets.Just change the sequence of your code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("title")

mainframe = Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


Label(mainframe, text='Left Label').grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(W, E), rowspan=2)

Label(mainframe, text="Center Area").grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=W, rowspan=2)

Label(mainframe, text="Right Label").grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=W, rowspan=2)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

Label(mainframe, background='white', text='asdasdasdasdasd', anchor=W, justify=LEFT, bd=1, relief='solid').grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=(W,E), columnspan=3, pady=0, ipady=0,padx=0,ipadx=0)
Entry(mainframe, background='white', bd=1, relief='sunken').grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=(W,E), columnspan=3, pady=0, ipady=0, padx=0,ipadx=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Now:

[image]